# Bridges, Castles and Bazaars with Die Belargerer (the Siege)

Tags: carcassonne, expansions

I was playing with the Bridges, Castles and Bazaars and Die Belargerer (a rerelease of The Siege with 6 tiles).

If you have one in a city, it causes the city to score 1 point per tile and 1 per pennant if it is completed. Now Castles Score what ever the next finished feature in it's 6 tile influence scores.

At the end of game a besieged city is worth 2 cities to a farmer and a castle is worth a +1.

So 3 of the 6 new tiles can be used to create the 'clam' cities you can use for castles.

The way we played is that by making it a castle, it is a castle and ignore the Siege tile from then on.

Is this the correct way to interpret the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using castles, if a 'clam city' is completed you then make the decision to either score it as a city or turn it into a castle. If it becomes a castle, then no scoring relating to *cities* applies to it (and scoring for the castle does not occur until and unless a neighboring feature is completed). Since the scoring of siege tiles only applies to cities, it does not affect the scoring of a castle. A castle is worth 4 points to a farmer.

Link to official rules:

http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Carcassonne_Exp8.pdf

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking along those lines but I'm glad to see it is backed up by the rules.